# laravel include php(sdk) use psr-4 is class not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, psr-4

Excuse me, I want to use this sdk [GitHub](https://github.com/ECPay/ECPayAIO_PHP/blob/master/AioSDK/sdk/ECPay.Payment.Integration.php)

I try include file php into laravel controller , but is not work.

then, I'll update composer.json, using PSR-4 .. is class XXX/XXX/  not found..

error message Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ECPay_AllInOne' not found

how can I do? please help me, thanks~

my project sdk file :

[image: image link]

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "ECPaySDK\\": "ECPaySDK/"
    },
    "files": [
        "ECPaySDK/ECPayPaymentIntegration.php"
    ]


},
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use ECPaySDK;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Travel_user;
use App\Travel_user_place;
use App\Place;
use App\Files;
use App\House;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
class BackendController extends Controller
```

sdk class

```
<?php
namespace ECPaySDK;
abstract class ECPay_PaymentMethod {
const ALL = 'ALL';
```

Comment: Did not understand the error mate? Please clarify.

Comment: @linuxartisan sorry, i'll update my error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding it to composer.json, import it to your class with `use` keyword. Change this

```
namespace ECPaySDK;
```

To

```
use ECPaySDK\ECPay_AllInOne;
```

In the format NAMESPACE\CLASSNAME;

For this to work, go at the top of your file and define a namespace. It seems there is no namespace for now. You can define like this

```
namespace ECPaySDK;
```

So depending on the class you want to use, prefix it with `ECPaySDK` namespace. Assuming you put your your SDK directory at the root of your application.

**Update**

You have a single file with multiple class declarations. Go to your composer file in the autoload part, just below `"psr-4"` create a new entry called `files`.

```
"files": [
    "ECPaySDK/ECPaymentIntegration.php"
]
```

Then run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: thanks your reply, i try this it , is also Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ECPay_AllInOne' not found...  , my update my question

Comment: @EddyTheDove I think OP needs to import `use ECPaySDK\ECPayPaymentIntegration`

Comment: Check my update. But before read my suggestions carefully. Remove `namespace ECPaySDK;` from your controller and change it to `use ECPaySDK;`

Comment: And please, import the class you actually need. I only gave you an example. That file has numerous classes. Only you and the author know what's in there. I did not read it. As per @NarendrasinghSisodia suggest, add this to your controller instead `use ECPaySDK\ECPayPaymentIntegration`

Comment: @EddyTheDove okay~! wait me!  now i try this

Comment: @EddyTheDove excuse me~! my update my question , i try this it , also Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ECPay_AllInOne' not found ... ,  Is there something wrong？  very thanks your help～！

Comment: Now I'm just getting dirty. This is not recommended. But try this and see if it makes a difference. In your controller, inside the function where you want to instantiate the payment object, do `include(base_path() . '\ECPaySDK\ECPaymentIntegration.php');` Then `pay = new ECPay_AllInOne();`

Comment: @EddyTheDove Thank you~!  my question is ok!  very thanks!